# Abandoned at embrace

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages

So I'm about to run a one-player Vampire: Dark Ages chronicle set in Poland. I want to have the player's character abandoned after embrace, as I want to keep the cast of characters small. Is clan Gangrel my only option or do vampires of some other clans occasionally abandon a childe? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Jason!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**They do.**

There's certainly textual support for it:

> Worse, some sires abandon
>   their childer completely, leaving them to the mercy of the
>   night without instruction or guidance. This fate usually
>   amounts to a death sentence for the childe, and few last
>   for more than a handful of nights before falling victims to
>   their own ignorance or the torches of enraged peasants. (*Dark Ages: Vampire*, page 30)

The ones who tend to abandon their embraces tend to be of the Low Clans: Gangrel, Nosferatu, and Malkavian in particular. These clans don't have a lot of faith in established lineages, and might well be punished for daring to embrace at all. The Gangrel have the advantage of being able to endure the predations of nature best, what with Protean and Fortitude as their in-clans, but the Nosferatu are known for being able to survive almost any hardship and the get of Malkav… well, their sires just don't care.

And, of course, I'd be remiss if I didn't at least raise the idea that in a chronicle with one player, you're free to make any changes or exceptions you like; player characters tend to lead exceptional lives, so if your player wants a Ventrue or Tzimisce orphan, have at. But, given an interest in keeping to canon, Gangrel, Nos, or Malkavian are the ones to pick.

Comment: Cheers. Nos or Malkavian could be interesting. Definitely want to keep to canon.

Comment: @JasonVoorhees I think Jadasc wasn't talking about changing canon. What I understood is: "It's rare that a Tzimisce or a Ventrue made an orphan, but, it could certainly happen (anyone can have a night of passion), so if you (or your player) want the character to be one of those rare specimens, go for it".

Comment: Although those clans are the way to go, canon wise. Going against cannon can actually aide the story depending on what a ST has in mind. A Ventrue childe with a prestigious sire that accidentally embraced during frenzy and forgot. A childe that failed her sire and was abandoned to the chagrin of the rest of the clan if found out. Said Camarilla childe finds it's way to the Sabbat and doesn't find out about its heritage for decades...

Comment: Remember, regardless of what's "normal," vampires are still _individuals_.